# Omit x axis levels with no data in a facetted plot and change widths of the bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

As you can see in the data below, some levels of the x axis variable "type" are missing for some of the facetting variables "items". For example, there is no "type = A" for "items = 32".

I want to get rid of the *empty space* along the x axis corresponding to non-existing "types" (e.g., type A for 32 items case).

Some data ("temp"):

```
 type   items     value
    A      16       6.3
    B      16       8.3
    C      16       7.9
    B      32       7.7
    C      32       8.3
    C      64       7.9
```

Code for plotting:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(temp, aes(x = type, y = value, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid( . ~ items)
```

[image]

=======================

**Edit:**

According to Joran's solution, setting `scales = "free_x"` is doing what I want. However, the widths of the bars become very large under the item numbers 32 and 64. Please help me to make the widths even for all the bars.

```
ggplot(temp, aes(x = type, y = value, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid( . ~ items, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Try `scales = "free_x"` in `facet_grid`, although you may have to use `facet_wrap`, I can't recall at the moment.

Comment: Joran: Thank you very much. It is working, but the widths of the bars becomes large for items no 32 and 64. Please let me know how can I control the widths of the bars.

Comment: `?facet_grid` : ... , space="free"

Comment: DWin: Thank you very much. My bad, I forgot about the help. :-)

Comment: I hope you have a good reason to do this. The white space is very informative, it gives the reader a head's up that those levels have value of 0 (which is still a value).

Comment: @kkp, are you still trying to solve this? Did you follow Etienne Low-Décarie suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply following the directions given by [joran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324364/joran) and [Etienne Low-Décarie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742447/etienne-low-decarie) to close this *old* unanswered question. Please up-vote [joran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324364/joran) and [Etienne Low-Décarie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742447/etienne-low-decarie).

Also, please note [Roman Luštrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322912/roman-lustrik)'s valuable comment above "*I hope you have a good reason to do this. The white space is very informative, it gives the reader a head's up that those levels have value of 0 (which is still a value)*."

```
# data
temp <- structure(list(type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), items = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 32L, 32L, 
64L), value = c(6.3, 8.3, 7.9, 7.7, 8.3, 7.9)), .Names = c("type", 
"items", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))

# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(temp, aes(type, value, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid( . ~ items, scales = "free_x", space = "free")
```

[image]